# yahoo hosting mysql server issues

Tags: mysql, shared-hosting

I have uploaded files on yahoo hosting , but when i open its phpmyadmin credentials of mysql work fine but same credentials not work in code . here is super easy code to connect my

```
   <?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username','password');
if (!$conn) {
            echo "<p>Could not connect to mysql server </p>\n";
            echo mysql_error();
        }
mysql_select_db('..CMS-2', $conn);
?>
```

some time it says 500 - Internal Server Error and some time it says message print in code  , i have also used mysql instead of localhost but no benefit

Could not connect to mysql server
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (46)

Comment: what is the message printed in code.. The internal server error will be probably caused by a typo in your code. Also please step away from mysql_* functions they are considered bad practice.

Comment: if i step away from mysql_connect , what should i use to connect mysql database

Comment: pdo http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php